# Prevent scrolling all the way up & down in iframe website

Tags: iframe, frameset-iframe

again

I was trying to iframe & display a content of a website inside my website. I was successful by displaying the content of the other website, but the problem is when the iframed website is added, it shows the whole content of that website. there are other links at the top and the bottom of that website. I wanted to display only the middle content.

I tried this code to disable scrolling, but it prevents the whole content from scrolling up & down.

I wanted to show only the middle content by disabling the scrolling up after some pixel (Like Start scrolling from this point.)
[image]

And Stop Scrolling down when some pixels remain to reach bottom  (Like stop scrolling when it reaches this point)
[image]

If (anyone gets my idea && it is possible) { please share it with me; }

Thanks.